# Amount of combinations of sets summing to number

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, integer-partitions

(Apologies for the confused arbitrariness here; I don't have experience in formal maths to make abstract my lay-person thoughts, but I've tried my best.)

I have $x$ identical but order-important sets of $0$ to $y$, and would like to make a selection from each set returning $\{N_1, N_2, … N_y\}$. Basic logic tells me there are $y^x$ different selections I can make. However, I am confused at how I may restrict the amount of possible selections so that the sum of these results – $\sum\limits_{i=1}^x N_i$ – is equal to arbitrary number $z$. I know how to determine  $f(x,y,z)$ using basic list scripting, but despite this cannot figure out how to define function $f$ itself.

Confused googling has turned me to the subjects of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) (which I understand works for unordered sets, but can be multiplied by $x!$ for order-important sets) and subsequently [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) (which returns the amount of possible permutations but does not factor in ordering of these and residual zeroes for other values). How do I reconcile my knowledge such that I can come to a formula which is easiest computable *en masse* rather than having to sum each possible set for each value?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking how many such possible selections are there that sum to $z$?

Comment: If you are looking for the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k=z$ in non-negative integers, that is done by Stars and Bars, please see Wikipedia. But I really don't know precisely what you are looking for.

Comment: I think you need to modify stars and bars though, because it seems like the question is putting a maximum value on $x_i$, so there are fewer ways to partition it.

Comment: @EricBrooks Yes.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In particular, I mean there are $x$ different sets, which are completely unique – so summing to 6 over two sets allows me {0,6}, {1,5} and so on. However, the difference between the comma/plus separation is that in this case the set ordering is important – $\{0, X\} \neq \{X\} \neq \{X, 0\}$ .

Comment: I believe this paper is what you want: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Eger/eger6.pdf